# IsNumeric vb 2012 fails to recognize double

Tags: vb.net

Visual Basic 2012. I use IsNumeric extensively as a test of correct data. Format of data tested is CSV string, split before processing. The code:

```
If IsNumeric(strCurr(12)) = True AndAlso IsNumeric(strPrev(12)) = True Then 

'do stuff

End If
```

The code block enclosed by the above is bypassed. The content tested is a double, in this case 117.34. (I understand that "= True" is redundant.)

"Most" of the time (as far as I know) IsNumeric performs correctly (meaning it recognizes the doubles saved as string and retrieved as being doubles). Why it would occasionally fail is a total mystery to me. Anyone ever have this happen? Or know why it would happen in some cases but not others?

It is not the content that is the problem. I remmed the IsNumeric test at the start of the code block, and code performs perfectly. The problem for me is that I have literally thousands of such tests throughout my apps and now I am wondering how many other code blocks are being bypassed as "not numeric" when in fact they are numeric.

Comment: Both tests are true? What is the content of strCurr(12) and strPrev(12) when the result is false? You can simply add an else and show the content of the two variables in case of false.